# List all sets of points in a plane that are enclosed by circles with given radius

Tags: geometry, algorithms, circles

My problem is: Given N points in a plane and a number R, list/enumerate all subsets of points, where points in each subset are enclosed by a circle with radius of R. Two subsets $S_i$ and $S_j$ should be different and not covered each other, i.e. $S_i/S_j \neq  \emptyset$ and $S_j/S_i \neq  \emptyset$.

Efficiency may not be much important, but the algorithm should not be too slow.

In a special case, can we find K subsets with most points? Approximation algorithm can be accepted.

Thanks,

Comment: @mvw: I rewrite the question for more clarification.

Comment: What operation is $S_i/S_j$?

Comment: @mvw: difference operation: items in $S_i$ but not in $S_j$

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your query, but instead shows that questions
within the same intellectual neighborhood can be intricate.

**Theorem**. Every point set of 12 points can be covered by disjoint unit disks.

> Aloupis, Greg, Robert A. Hearn, Hirokazu Iwasawa, and Ryuhei Uehara. "Covering Points with Disjoint Unit Disks." In *CCCG*, pp. 41-46. 2012.
>   ([PDF download](http://2012.cccg.ca/papers/paper13.pdf).)

---

[image: GregDisks]

---